# How does Python's matplotlib.pyplot.quiver exactly work?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to understand how the [quiver](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver) function in the NumPy module works. Supposedly it allows to visualize graphically the values of two arrays, for example horizontal and vertical velocities. I have the following very simple example, but I show it just to see if you can help me to find out what I'm not doing well:

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,11)
y = np.linspace(1,0,11)
u = v = np.zeros((11,11))
u[5,5] = 0.2

plt.quiver(x, y, u, v)
```

The code produces the following figure:

[image: http://imgur.com/Rg3ZoHl]

As you can see, the arrow is not an arrow, but a line and it is longer than 0.2. My intention is to get an arrow of length 0.2 and I thought I could do it using `quiver`. Is it possible? Or should I better use another command?

Comment: FYI: `quiver` is from matplotlib, not numpy.

Comment: What do you mean *"how does [it] work"*? Have you tried reading it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sure. I mean I understood it would do what I said but it doesnt

Answer (score 25, accepted):

matplotlib quiver does auto scaling. Set the scale to `1` to get your 0.2 units in x an y:

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,11)
y = np.linspace(1,0,11)
u = v = np.zeros((11,11))
u[5,5] = 0.2

plt.quiver(x, y, u, v, scale=1)
```

[image]

If you don't set `scale`, matplotlib uses an auto scaling algorithm based on the average vector length and the number of vectors. Since you only have one vector with a length greater zero, it becomes really big. Adding more vectors makes the arrows successively smaller.

To have equal x and y extensions of your arrow a few more adjustments are needed:

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,11)
y = np.linspace(1,0,11)
u = v = np.zeros((11,11))
u[5,5] = 0.2

plt.axis('equal')
plt.quiver(x, y, u, v, scale=1, units='xy')
```

Both axes need to be equal and the units need to be set to `xy`.

[image]

Comment: I'm really missing something about this quiver API. I googled to find a simple example of drawing a single line with `quiver`, and instead I get an input with shapes `(11,)`, `(11,)`, `(11, 11)`, and `(11, 11)`...

Answer (score 5):

Not related to your problem, but interesting to mention: Funny thing is that by writing `u[5, 5] = 0.2` you are implying`v[5, 5] = 0.2` as well (as shown in your diagonal arrow), since before you wrote `u = v = np.zeros((11, 11))`. You could avoid that by writing

```
u = np.zeros((11, 11))
v = np.zeros((11, 11))
```

to make `u` and `v` independent from each other.

Answer (score 2):

The quiver function visualizes a vector field, like this:

[image: example quiver plot]

(from the [examples page](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html)). In this type of plot, the vector at a point represents the magnitude of the field vector at that point. For example, if you're visualizing velocity of a fluid, the length of the arrow represents the speed of the fluid.

You can think of a vector field as a function mapping input (position) to output (the vector, e.g. velocity). The output values have no relation to the input positions; in particular, they may not even be measured in the same units! So a quiver plot can only show the *relative* magnitude of the field at different points - only the relative lengths of the arrows are meaningful, not their absolute lengths.

In other words, you shouldn't expect a field value of 0.2 to be represented by an arrow of length 0.2 in data units.

However, matplotlib provides an option you can specify to do that: the `scale_units` option to `quiver`. According to the documentation, you can give `scale_units = 'xy'` and it will render the arrow lengths using the same units as the axes.